# Material properties for a node in a 2-material FEM code

Tags: finite-element

I'm trying to debug an FEM that I inherited, and I unfortunately do not have much knowledge of FEM. I only know FD and FVM.

If you're modeling a system with 2 materials, there will be an interface location between the 2 materials, where on one side are elements of one material, and on the other side are elements of the second material. These elements share a common node. When you assign things like material properties to that node, do you typically take an average between the properties of the 2 elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally don't assign material properties to a node. They are part of a subdomain and, hence, "assigned" to an element. They appear in the integrals you compute, e.g.

$$\int\limits_{\Omega_e} k \nabla u \nabla w d\Omega\, ,$$

here $\Omega_e$ represents the element identified as $e$.

Nevertheless, due to interpolation the computed integrals are added to the nodes. In that sense, you end up with properties that are somewhat (area/volume) averaged, but not exactly.

Comment: Ah I see. If I'm not mistaken, inputs such as material properties are assigned to the elements, as you said, and then the solution is obtained for the nodes?

Comment: Yes, that is the way that it is commonly done. You could go a step further and define the properties for each Gauss point, but that's not usual.

Comment: Is there an actual concept of "shared" nodes in FEM? E.g., at the interface between 2 materials, that node would technically be physically "shared," but numerically, is that node sort of duplicated (e.g., in this case that 1 physical node would be treated as 2 nodes numerically, one for the element on each side of the interface)?